# What am I doing wrong when trying to deserialize json into a c# list?

Tags: c#, json

I have a Product class:

```
class Product 
    {
        public string Name;
    }
```

A Product List class:

```
   class ProductDataFile
    {
        public List<Product>? products;

    }
```

And a class for loading json into these classes:

```
public void LoadProducts()
 {
   string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(FileLoc);
   ProductDataFile? productDataFile= JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ProductDataFile>(jsonString);
   var ProductName = productDataFile.products.First().Name;
 }
```

This throws a "System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')". I used the debugger and products is null, so that seems to be the problem.

My Json looks something like this:

````
{
  "listOfProducts": "List of products",
  "products": [
    {
      "Name": "product one"
    }
  ]
}
```
````

Comment: Please attach the sample JSON data. Thanks!

Comment: And also when you debugged did you verify the jsonString and productDataFile weren't null?

Comment: Yes the jsonString is fine, it contains the proper json data. Json is added to post now.

Comment: Your json does not match your classes, it is case sensitive. Either change your class and property names to match, or decorate them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library `Newtonsoft.json` method of `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` need to use properties instead of fields, otherwise you might not `Deserialize` anything from your JSON data.

```
class Product 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class ProductDataFile
{
    public List<Product>? products {get;set;}

}
```

I would suggest you use [json2csharp](https://json2csharp.com/), it can easy to get the model by `JSON` and make sure it will be work.

Comment: This fixed it, thanks you so much!

Comment: @CodeMan No problem glad to help